# How to pass parameters from textInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, foreach

I am using ReactNative and I am having problem passing a parameter. How can I pass a paremeter to TextInput?
ERROR is"Text strings must be rendered within a  Component"

````
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
    <Text>What is your name? </Text>

    <TextInput 
    placeholder =  'Type something'
    onChangeText = {(text) => setName({text})}
    //value = {name}
    />
      <Button 
      title = 'Push me'/>
      onPress = {()=> {alert('hello '+ $name)}}
    </View>



  );
}```
````

Comment: What error did you get ? ... Hint: pass text directly to `setText` ... `onChangeText = {(text) => setName(text)}`

Comment: Can you define the problem in a clear way, please? Do you get the error when you try to pass value={name} ?

Comment: ERROR is"Text strings must be rendered within a Component"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing tag is miss-placed ... so, you're rendering `onPress = {()=> {alert('hello '+ $name)}}` as **plain text** not **JSX**

```
<Button 
      title = 'Push me'/> // <---Look at this
      onPress = {()=> {alert('hello '+ $name)}}
```

Instead

```
<Button 
  title = 'Push me'
  onPress = {()=> {alert('hello '+ $name)}} />
```

Along with the issue I mentioned in the comment-section

Comment: Happy coding...!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this   
 <TextInput placeholder =  'Type something'
        onChangeText = {(text) => setName(text)}
        //value = {name}
    />
```